# React scroll to top when opening a new page not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need react to open new pages from the top.

My goToTop.js:

```
    import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

Sometimes it does scroll to the top and sometimes it doesn't. It seems as if the element that the user clicked on is lower than the size of the next page it won't work. I'm confused on why this does not work.

I've tried this in the componentOnMount and componentOnUpdate:

```
var something = document.getElementById('someid')
something.scrollIntoView()
```

But this does not work either. It can not find the element in unmount and it does not work in update

My app.js looks like this:

```
return (
    <StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <ScrollToTop />
        <header className='navMenu'>
          <div className='navMenuInside'>
            <div className='navMenuCenter'>
              <Link onClick={handleLinkClick}>About</Link>
              <Link className="activeMenu" to="/">Projects</Link>
              <Link onClick={sendEmail}>E-mail</Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/projects/:id" element={<Details />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Projects />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer 
                linkedin={info.linkedin} 
                />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </StrictMode>
  );
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include a [mcve] that reproduces this scrolling issue? It's likely, as you say, dependent on the *actual* page content. For example, if the window is already scrolled to the top but is rendering a scrollable container then *that* container needs to be scrolled. What version of `react-router` are you using? V6 has some scrolling-to-top/scroll-restoration utilities.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could inspect live?

Comment: Codesandbox is effectively a VSCode clone that runs in the browser. If you already have familiarity with VSCode it'll feel like second nature, otherwise I find it to be an easy UI to get into. We don't need the entire project, just a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.4.4" to answer your first question :)

Comment: If you could dump that second snippet with the links and routes, and the `Details` and `Projects` component into a sandbox, along with some mock data examples it would likely be enough to see what the code is doing overall.

Comment: @DrewReese like this? https://codesandbox.io/embed/pedantic-dubinsky-b1mlb3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250559/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-marty).

Answer (score 2):

You should try to make an `Wrapped component`

something like this :

```
const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [location.pathname]);
  return children;
};
```

then wrapp it around your App or component

```
<Wrapper>
    <App/>
</Wrapper>
```

Comment: Thanks, i like the idea! However, im getting this error: Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. I've added my app.js to the question

Comment: This is a wrapper component, not a Higher Order Component; they are different patterns.

Comment: yup, that's what I meant. that is why I name the component Wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with children from the Cyrus Zei's answer. Simply create a component and use it before App component.

In Component:

```
export const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [location]);

  return null;
}
```

No use it before App component:

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <ScrollToTop/>
      <App/>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
```